# Ajax results to load into a iframe

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a Ajax post that returns the path to a PDF file i can not seem to get it to open the pdf in an Iframe of on the parent page.

Parent Page:

```
     <div  id = "mainpage" ></div>
     <iframe class ="box2" id="myFrame2"  width="600px" height="700px"   scrolling="yes" align="right">
     </iframe>
</div>
<script>
  function onAjaxComplete(msg)
    {
      $("#mainpage").html(msg);
      // alert(msg);
      }
```

when I click on the ajax request it returns the correct value and the function will display the results in the div but I can not get it to open the pdf file in the iframe.

This is the PHP script for the call from Ajax:

```
 <?php
  $sitej = $_POST['site'];
  $filenamej = $_POST['filename'];
  $pagej = $_POST['page'];
  $path = "scann/" . $sitej . "/" . $filenamej;

  //var_dump($_POST);
 $load = "$path/#page=$pagej ";
 //$open =      '<a href="' . $path . '/#page=' . $pagej . '">';
  //$load = '<a  target="myFrame2" href="'. $open . '">';
 echo $load;

 ?>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How does your end result in the `div` look like?

Comment: scann/Cairns/201605111102.pdf/#page=0

Comment: That is what your `div` element contains? Or is that the url you want your `iframe` to show?

Comment: sorry that's what is showing in the div . it is the path to the pdf file i want to pen in the Iframe

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to add the `msg` to the `iframe` src attribute:

```
function onAjaxComplete(msg){
      $("#myFrame2").attr('src', msg); //No reason to select the div if you want to change the iframe src
      // alert(msg);
}
```

This will return the `iframe` with the src from the php file.

Comment: i have made that change but no luck,

Comment: <script>
        function onAjaxComplete(msg)
        {
     $("#myFrame2").src(msg);
 
         }
       </script>

Comment: Sorry try: function onAjaxComplete(msg) { $("#myFrame2").attr('src', msg); }

Comment: thanks for your help that worked but not quite when i click on the link it should open to a set page  scann/Cairns/201605111102.pdf#page17 but it will only open the document at the first page. what i was hoping that when they click on the Thumnail to the side it changes the scann/Cairns/201605111102.pdf#page Number and i was hoping it would open on that page. is it possible what what i am doing  ? thanks for your time

Comment: I have this working now that the correct loading of the page but when a user selects another page from the list the Iframe will not update any surgestions on how to make the Iframe reload with the new Page request. i have confirmed that the correct path is sent to the iframe with the new page number

Comment: When the src is set the iframe should reload automatically. Can you please confirm that the src does in fact get updated?